# Обновление данных за каждую неделю

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Разрабатываю систему учета использую Laravel.
Задача состоит в том что бы выводить данные из базы только за одну неделю (последнюю).Так как заказчик проводит учет раз в неделю
Я реализовал вывод таким образом

```
$name = Order::whereBetween('working_time', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])->get();
```

Вопрос состоит в том что бы реализовать вывод и обновление в соответствии с неделей.На момент написания 05.01.19 я добавил данных с 31.12.18 по  13.01.19 но оно выводит почему то только с 31.12.18  по 06.01.19 .По идее после добавления след недели оно должно выводить именно ее.Но я не понимаю в чем проблема

---

Comment: `Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()` `now()` - текущее время. так что выводит записи для **текущей** недели, что и логично.

Comment: как тогда лучше сделать не подскажете?

Comment: Зависит от задачи, но из решений в 1 запрос, да еще и с ларавелем - не подскажу. Сначало вытащить из базы номер последней хранящейся недели, а уже после на основании этих данных делать запрос.

Comment: задача состоит в том что бы выводить данные только за последнюю неделю  в базе

Comment: Об этом я и говорю вам, первым запросом вытаскиваете номер(дату) последней присутствующей в базе недели, а потом уже делаете запрос на сами данные за эту неделю. По конкретным методам ларавеля - не подскажу, я с ним не знаком, для решения на чистом php\MySQL - нехватает данных в вопросе, а именно структуры БД.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение таким образом

```
$name = \App\Order::whereBetween('working_time',[Carbon::today()->startOfWeek(),Carbon::today()->endOfWeek()])->get();
```